# Speeding up code with Boyer-Moor algorithm

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

Now I'm trying to make my lab but I have unpassed test due to time limit so I need to speed up code execution a little bit, but idk how. So for my task I have to put in out numbers of lines and number of word in line where the subline is. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int WordCount(const string &s, const int &index) {
    int words = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        if (s[i] == ' ')
            words++;
    return words + 1;
}

void toLower(string &s) {
    for (char &c: s)
        c = tolower(c);
}

void removeExtraSpaces(string &input) {
    input.erase(input.begin(), find_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [](const int &ch) {
        return ch != ' ';
    }));
    input.erase(find_if(input.rbegin(), input.rend(), [](const int &ch) {
        return ch != ' ';
    }).base(), input.end());
    auto new_end = std::unique(input.begin(), input.end(), [](const int &left, const int &right) {
        return left == ' ' && right == ' ';
    });
    input.erase(new_end, input.end());
}

void Boyer_Moore(const string &str, const string &substr, vector<int> &result) {

    vector<int> shifts_table(256, substr.size());
    for (int i = substr.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        shifts_table[substr[i]] = std::min(shifts_table[substr[i]], (int) substr.size() - 1 - i);

    int i = substr.size() - 1;
    while (i < str.size()) {
        int j = i;
        int last = i;
        int k = substr.size() - 1;
        while (k >= 0) {
            if (substr[k] == str[j]) {
                k--;
                j--;
            } else {
                i += shifts_table[str[last]];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (k == -1) {
            if ((j < 0 || str[j] == ' ') &&
                (j + substr.size() + 1 >= str.size() || str[j + substr.size() + 1] == ' ')) {
                result.emplace_back(j + 1);
            }
            i += shifts_table[str[last]];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    ifstream f("input.txt");
    string textLine;
    string line;
    string find_string;
    getline(f, find_string);
    toLower(find_string);
    vector<string> text;
    while (getline(f, line)) {
        removeExtraSpaces(line);
        toLower(line);
        text.emplace_back(line);
        if (!line.empty())
            textLine += std::move(line) + ' ';
    }
    int str_index = 0;
    int start_pos = 0;
    vector<int> result;
    Boyer_Moore(textLine, find_string, result);
    for (const auto &value: result) {
        while (str_index < text.size() && start_pos + text[str_index].size() <= value)
            start_pos += text[str_index].size() + (text[str_index++].empty() ? 0 : 1);
        if (str_index < text.size())
            cout << (str_index + 1) << ", " << WordCount(text[str_index], value - start_pos) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I really want to speed up the part with loop after Boyer_Moore function but I don't know how, have any ideas?

here's one benchmark:
Input:

```
cat dog cat dog bird
CAT dog CaT Dog Cat DOG bird CAT
dog cat dog bird
```

Output:

```
1, 3
1, 8
```

If it's needed I will supply more

Comment: No need to wrote that yourself: [`std::boyer_moore_searcher`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/boyer_moore_searcher)

Comment: Also wondering if Boyer-Moore is the optimal algorithm for such short strings. It has quite a heavy setup cost for the tables.

Comment: what exactly is the code supposed to do? What is your task?

Comment: My task is to put in output the number of line in text and number of word in this line corresponding substring and I have to do it using Boyer Moore algorithm